# On the number of integers whose prime factors are congruent to 1 modulo some given number.

Tags: number-theory

Let $m\ge2$ be an integer,
$$
A_m=\{k\in\mathbb{N}:\text{all prime factors of $k$ are}\equiv1\pmod m\},
$$
and $C_m(x)$ the counting function of $A_m$, that is, for $x>0$
$$
C_m(x)=\#\{k\in A_m:k\le x\}.
$$
For instance $A_2$ is the set of odd integers, and $C_2(x)\sim x/2$. As another example,
$$
A_3=\{1, 7, 13, 19, 31, 37, 43, 49, 61, 67, 73, 79, 91, 97, 103,\dots\}
$$
is sequence [A004611](https://oeis.org/A004611).

By the prime number theorem on arithmetic progressions we have
$$
\frac{1}{\phi(m)}\,\frac{x}{\log x}\le C_m(x)\le\frac{x}{m}.
$$
Is anything known about the asymptotic behavior of $C_m(x)$ for $m>2$?

Comment: Heuristically, I would expect $C_m(N)$ to be like $$\frac{1}{\varphi(m)}\sum_{p<N} 1+ \frac{1}{\varphi^2(m)}\sum_{pq<N}1+\cdots+\frac{1}{\varphi^k(m)}\sum_{pqr\cdots z < N} 1+\cdots,$$ by [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). The inner sums are probably well approximated by some manipulations involving $\pi(N^{1/k})$, which in turn might be combined with the prime number theorem to yield an asymptotic. Disclaimer: this is a stretch, I'm not familiar with such problems.

Comment: @IanMateus I tried to approximate the second of those sums, but was not successful.

Comment: I think this possible in principle. Write $[1,N] = [1, N^{1/2}]\cup[N^{1/4}, N^{1/2}]\cup[N^{1/2}, N^{3/4}][N^{3/4}, N]$. Then the second sum is approximately $$\frac{1}{2}\left[\pi(N^{1/2})^2 + (\pi(N^{1/2}) - \pi(N^{1/4}))(\pi(N^{3/4}) - \pi(N^{1/2}))+ \pi(N^{1/4})(\pi(N) - \pi(N^{3/4}))\right].$$

Keeping only the relevant powers and using the prime number theorem, this should be asymptotic to $$\frac{10}{3}\frac{N^{5/4}}{\log^2(N)}.$$

Comment: In general, the $n$th sum is asymptotic to $$\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\pi(N^{k/2n})\pi(N^{(2n+1-k)/2n}),$$

which is like $$\frac12  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2nN^{k/2n}}{k\log(N)} \frac{N^{1-(k/2n)+(1/2n)}}{\left(1-(k/2n)  +(1/2n)\right)\log(N)}  =\frac{4n^2H_{2n}N^{(2n+1)/2n}}{(2n+1) \log^2N}$$ by the prime number theorem.

Comment: The last formula should be $(2n^2H_{2n}N^{(2n+1)/2n})/((2n+1) \log^2N)$, sorry. We should expect, then, $$C_m(N)\sim\frac{N}{\log^2 N}\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{2n^2}{2n+1}H_n \frac{N^{1/2n}}{\varphi^n(m)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I find this particular problem interesting. So we are basically looking at the probability that a random integer $n$, all primes $p | n$ are congruent to $1\pmod m$. A well known mathematical result states that a random integer $n$, has on average, $\ln(\ln n)$ prime factors. So the probability all of these prime factors are congruent to $1 \pmod m$ is about $\left(\frac{1}{\phi(m)^{\ln(\ln n)}}\right)$ and we should expect

$$C_m(n) ≈ \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{\phi(m)^{\ln(\ln k)}}\right)$$

Note that the sum diverges for any particular $m$.

There is a better estimate: For all primes $q ≠ 1 \pmod m$, we want the probability such that $n$ is not divisible by $q$, which is $\left(\frac{q-1}{q}\right)$. In particular, for all primes $k<\sqrt n$:

$$K(n) = \prod_{k<\sqrt{n}} \left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)$$

and for all primes $p=1\pmod m$

$$P_m(n) = \prod_{p<\sqrt{n}} \left(\frac{p-1}{p}\right)$$

The probability $n$ has all prime factors congruent to $1\pmod m$ is $\left(\frac{K(n)}{P_m(n)}\right)$.

Like with the previous estimate, we should be able to sum these probabilties to get an estimate for $C_m(n)$.